# Where can I learn about DNS settings

Tags: dns

I am trying to learn how to configurate DNS settings. Tried goolging and wikipedia, but I can't find any tutorials about DNS settings.

I bought a domain from google/enom and I need to redirect it to my hosting server. Anyone know anything that I can read to get a good understanding?

Answer (score 2):

A great simple guide: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48090

Further reading, try these

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names

A bigger read: http://www.gnc-web-creations.com/dns-tutorial.htm

Any other questions, just ask.

You may want to look at the pro webmasters (also owned by stack exchange): https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/